# What is path //, how is it different from /?

Tags: linux, path, kernel, posix

We know the root directory is `/`, and according to POSIX, there is another directory `//` which differs from `/`.

When you `ls /` and `ls //`, the output is the same, so is `stat`, however if you `cd /` and `cd //`, they are different, though the directory content are the same.

That really confused me. Anyone got an answer?

Comment: Can you provide a reference which says they are different? Also, what do you mean if you "cd /" vs. "cd //" they are different -- how do you know?

Comment: @MarkkuK. Sorry I didn't say it clear, it means pwd didn't change. So as devnull said. You can try it.

Comment: Additionally, if you type "cd //usr" (for example) instead of "cd /usr", you end up in "/usr", bash says you are un "//usr" and pwd is "//usr" too...

Comment: [How does Linux handle multiple consecutive path separators (/home////username///file)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1910)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From [Bash FAQ](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/FAQ), with formatting applied:

> E10) Why does `cd //` leave `$PWD` as `//`?
>
> POSIX.2, in its description of `cd`, says that *three* or more leading
> slashes may be replaced with a single slash when canonicalizing the
> current working directory.
>
> This is, I presume, for historical compatibility.  Certain versions of
> Unix, and early network file systems, used paths of the form
> `//hostname/path` to access `path` on server `hostname`.

Comment: On my git bash emulation (technically a windows machine) an attempt to `ls -l //` results in the machine trying to read and list the entire available network... wow.