# In Bash, why does `cd //` work (and equal `cd /`)?

Tags: linux, bash

It is fairly well known that `cd /` in Bash/terminal takes you to your root directory, regardless of where you were before:

```
brian@brian-linux:~/redis-3.0.3$ cd /
brian@brian-linux:/$ pwd
/
brian@brian-linux:/$ ls
bin    dev         initrd.img.old  libx32      opt   sbin  usr
boot   etc         lib             lost+found  proc  srv   var
cdrom  home        lib32           media       root  sys   vmlinuz
data   initrd.img  lib64           mnt         run   tmp   vmlinuz.old
brian@brian-linux:/$
```

I stumbled upon an interesting discovery today:

In Bash, `cd //` takes you to directory `//`, which is the same as the root directory, but is still described as `//`:

```
brian@brian-linux:~/redis-3.0.3$ cd //
brian@brian-linux://$ ls
bin    dev         initrd.img.old  libx32      opt   sbin  usr
boot   etc         lib             lost+found  proc  srv   var
cdrom  home        lib32           media       root  sys   vmlinuz
data   initrd.img  lib64           mnt         run   tmp   vmlinuz.old
brian@brian-linux://$ pwd
//
```

What's going on here, and why is this the case?

---

It's also worth noting that `cd ///` or any number of `/` greater than 2 will take you to the root directory `/`. However, from the root directory, `cd //` takes you to `//`:

```
brian@brian-linux:/$ cd ///
brian@brian-linux:/$ cd //
brian@brian-linux://$
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/23808/what-is-the-double-slash-directory

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840916/what-is-path-how-is-it-different-from

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11964/what-do-double-slashes-mean-in-unix-path-is-cd-dir-subdir-valid

Comment: Nothing to do with bash -- you'd have the same thing in every other language, ie. `os.chdir()` in Python. Not a bash question, shouldn't be tagged bash, etc.

Comment: I observed that while `//` points to `/root` and rest all `//....//` point out to `/`! Kinda dumbstruck...

Comment: @shekharsuman, what `//` does is implementation-defined, so your operating system can make it point anywhere without violating POSIX. That said, `/root` is an unusual choice; it's mostly just `/`.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy for clarifying. I am going through all the links mentioned here. Thanks again.,,

Comment: Thanks @PaulRoub, sorry for the duplicate. Google wasn't behaving with the //.

Answer (score 1):

You can have any number of `/` in file paths. `/this/file/path` is completely equivalent to `/this//file/////path`.

I'm not sure if this is the reason, but it means that you are less likely to get errors when automatically generating paths. For example:

```
get_project_root() {
    echo "/the/project/root/"
}

get_project_data_subdirectory() {
    echo "data"
}
```

If I wanted to use these functions to `cd` to the project's `data` directory I could do this:

```
project_root=$(get_project_root)
data_directory=$(get_project_data_directory)

cd "${project_root}/${data_directory}"
```

Now the `cd` command actually ran:

```
cd /the/project/root//data
```

Because I added a `/` inbetween the 2 variables. I did this because I might not know if the function will return a trailing `/`, it doesn't *need* to and some functions might not. The fact that you can have any number of slashes means that you can add them in to be safe without worrying about breaking the command.

Comment: Double leading slashes are technically different actually.

Comment: ...and I've seen a few filesystems that honor those differences (ie. AFS).

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of that. On my system cd // is the same as cd /.

Comment: BTW, you can't legally return strings from shell functions; you can emit them on stdout, but that's different.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Very true, I've changed the code. When I started writing the answer I wasn't aiming for shell code, then changed my mind half way through.

Comment: Made a few further fixes re: shell syntax; hope you don't mind. (Using `${foo}` vs `$foo` is pure stylistic preference when not trailed by characters valid in variable names, but `$foo` vs `"$foo"` has real differences in correctness).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Not at all! Thanks. I'm pretty sure my shell syntax is often questionable.