# python pathlib purepath - Why is are double slashes considered special?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I am struggling to understand why in the python purepath library this holds:

```
>>> pathlib.PurePath("/root") == pathlib.PurePath("///root")
    True
```

and this also:

```
>>> pathlib.PurePath("/root") == pathlib.PurePath("////root")
True
```

but this does not:

```
>>> pathlib.PurePath("/root") == pathlib.PurePath("//root")
    False
```

What is the reasoning behind this and is there any way to change that behavior (which would ignoring multiple consecutive slashes and just replacing it by one slash)?

Comment: What OS? The docs say it delegate to either PurePosixPath or PureWindowsPath. What is the behavior if specifically using the _other_ implementation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is path //, how is it different from /](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840916/what-is-path-how-is-it-different-from)

Comment: I am on linux. @thatotherguy thanks, that almost answers my question - any way to change this behavior?